# const errorDetails = { message: err.message, status: err.status, stackHighlighted: err.stack.replace(/[a-z_-\d]+.js:\d+:\d+/gi, '<mark>$&</mark>') };

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting an illegal character range error at `.replace()`. How would I fix this?

```
err.stack.replace(/[a-z_-\d]+.js:\d+:\d+/gi, '<mark>$&</mark>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the '-' character appears as a literal it should be either the first or last character, otherwise it denotes a character range, ie `[_-\d]` is the set of all characters between '_' and '\d'. But `[_\d-]` is the set of '_', '\d', and '-'.

Comment: so for the expression [a-z_-\d] should i put - at the end instead?

Comment: yup, or at the start, just not between two other characters.